# Nested flexbox row wrap order?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am designing a nested flexbox for variable screen width. There should be three boxes, arranged in the following way:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="object obj1"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="object obj2"></div>
    <div class="object obj3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrapper1 is 100% wide with centered content.

Now I want the following scenario.

1. When screen is wide enough, the three boxes must be arranged in a horizontal row.
2. When screen is narrow enough, the three boxes must be arranged in a vertical column.
3. When screen width is such that only 2 boxes fit horizontally, wrapper1's row should not break, whereas wrapper2's row should, creating the following disposition:
   [image: Blue border: wrapper1, Red border: wrapper2]

My problem is that I can't find a flex configuration to do this. What I've tried so far:

1. Using `flex: 1 0 auto;` on wrapper2. This works as far as row breaks are concerned, but wrapper2 does not shrink to its content's width, so the boxes lose center and flush to the left.
2. Using `flex: 0 1 <2 * object-width>;` on wrapper2. This keeps together wrapper2's row too strongly, and breaks wrapper1's row instead. (Against scenario No. 3.)
3. Using `flex: 0 1 auto` or setting `max-width: min-content;` on wrapper2, but this never lets wrapper2's row to stretch out horizontally. (Against scenario No. 1.)

So I'm asking you gurus out there if it is possible at all to realize a solution for my design.

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqz6ssmf/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a media query (or script) to accomplish that properly, and the reason is that when the children won't fit their parent's width, it's the outer siblings that will wrap, before inner one's does, and this is the normal wrapping order, regardless of using Flexbox or not.

Since we know the width of each item, sum them plus the borders, and we get a break point at 608px + the body margin, which I here reset to 0, as it might differ between the browsers.

Then, at the break point, you simply e.g. change `flex: 1 0 auto` to `flex: 0 0 auto`, and it will wrap and center properly.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqz6ssmf/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.object {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.obj1 {
  background-color: #aaccaa;
}
.obj2 {
  background-color: #ccaaaa;
}
.obj3 {
  background-color: #aaaacc;
}

@media (max-width: 608px) {
  .wrapper2 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="object obj1"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="object obj2"></div>
    <div class="object obj3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Gotta confess, I was unwilling to use a media query because my real project is more complicated, but I see this will be the only way to do it. Kudos!

Comment: @terminus.technicus Thanks :) ... Sometimes media queries doesn't do it for me either, and when one want to have a break point based on an element instead of the viewport, I use a very small script, attached to the resize event, and toggle a class to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Good idea... I've never done that, but will definitely check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-direction: column` in `.wrapper2` at breakpoint *(max-width:600px)*. I have done some changes in your css too.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.object {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.obj1 {
  background-color: #aaccaa;
}

.obj2 {
  background-color: #ccaaaa;
}

.obj3 {
  background-color: #aaaacc;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .wrapper2 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media (max-width:400px) {}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="object obj1"></div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="object obj2"></div>
    <div class="object obj3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/sqz6ssmf/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the same issue. I have 3 inner divs and I want the middle one to wrap first.

Solved it by using `float:right` and `float:left` then `float:left` or `float:right` for the middle div.

Downside is you can't use flex-grow etc but was not needed for my problem.

Comment: You can use `order` to make the middle wrap first: https://jsfiddle.net/sqz6ssmf/6/ ... upside, you can keep Flexbox and avoid `float`

Comment: @LGSon this is very nice. Post it as an answer and I'll make it the accepted answer

Comment: @terminus.technicus I already did...the one you accepted as well :)

Comment: Oh, you're right :D I didn't notice the @media query, only the order: -1 thing which seemed so elegant. But there is no royal road to elegance then, I see :)